# Why is there no option to install alongside win7 with the 12.04 LTS CD?

Tags: system-installation

I just downloaded both the 32-bit version of 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin and burned it onto CD. When trying to install there is no option to install alongside win7. I tried the 11.10 CD and the option was there. I ended up having to install 11.10 and then upgrading to 12.04 online. Why was there no option to install alongside win7 with the 12.04 LTS CD?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure. But you can boot into the LiveCD, then use gparted to shrink your windows 7 partition, and then reboot into windows 7 to make sure it's clean. Then you can reboot to the LiveCD and install Ubuntu. If windows 7 craps out on you from changing the partition size. You can fix the boot repair process with the free CD downloads from: http://neosmart.net/blog/2009/windows-7-system-repair-discs/ . You may want to download those and have them ready, if you don't have a windows cd.